# Checkbox CSS fix for Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Checkbox in Safari is overlaying the text. No issues in other browsers. Please see an image and the code code below. Other posts are not answering this. How do I fix that?

[image: checkbox in Safari]

```
// Checkbox Div from React Component

               <div id="chxContainer">
                <p id="chxName">New:</p>
                <label className="four wide column">
                  <input
                    className="ui checkbox"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="{checked}"
                    onChange={() => setChecked((checked) => !checked)}
                  />
                </label>
              </div>

/* below checkbox styles */

#chxContainer {
  margin: 2.2rem 0rem 0 2rem;
}

#chxName {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* below Global checkbox styles */

"@global": {

 ".ui.checkbox": {
      margin: "1.1rem 0 0 0.5rem",
      width: "5rem",
    },
}
```

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;` from `chxName`. If it is `absolute` positioned then it comes out of its normal flow.

Comment: Either it should be `position: relative` or remain as default `position: static`

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. It helped a bit but the checkbox is still very close to the button in comparison with other browsers.

Comment: just added some margin and it worked well. Thank you again.

Comment: That's a spacing issue. Of course, you can add some `margin`.